# I'm having trouble implenting "useContext" with typeScript in my app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-context

I had no problem using context in regular JS but typeScript is giving me a hard time. I've read over the docs and looked at some examples but I'm still missing something. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

## Context Component

```
import { ReactNode, createContext, useState } from 'react'

const DialogContext = createContext<DialogContext | null>(null)

function DialogProvider({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) {
  const [player1ButtonText, setPlayer1ButtonText] = useState('SELECT PLAYER 1')
  const [player2ButtonText, setPlayer2ButtonText] = useState('SELECT PLAYER 2')
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)
  function handleOpen() {
    setOpen(true)
  }
  function handleClose() {
    setOpen(false)
  }

  return (
    <DialogContext.Provider
      value={{
        open,
        handleOpen,
        handleClose,
        player1ButtonText,
        setPlayer1ButtonText,
        player2ButtonText,
        setPlayer2ButtonText,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </DialogContext.Provider>
  )
}

export { DialogProvider, DialogContext }
```

## Component using context

```
export default function SelectPlayerBox() {
  const { handleOpen, player1ButtonText, player2ButtonText } =
    useContext(DialogContext)
  return (...
```

## App component

```
...
<DialogProvider>
   <SelectPlayerBox />
</DialogProvider>
...
```

Comment: I think OP is getting some type errors or warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the type of your context value explicitly and pass it as a generic parameter to the createContext function. This way, TypeScript can infer the type of your context value and check if it matches the value you pass to the `Provider` component.

For example:

```
type DialogContextType = {
  player1ButtonText: string;
  setPlayer1ButtonText: (text: string) => void;
  player2ButtonText: string;
  setPlayer2ButtonText: (text: string) => void;
  open: boolean;
  handleOpen: () => void;
  handleClose: () => void;
};

const DialogContext = createContext<DialogContextType>({
  player1ButtonText: "SELECT PLAYER 1",
  setPlayer1ButtonText: () => {},
  player2ButtonText: "SELECT PLAYER 2",
  setPlayer2ButtonText: () => {},
  open: false,
  handleOpen: () => {},
  handleClose: () => {}
});
```

You can see the whole example here: [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-galileo-d9zsxx?file=/src/App.tsx)